# Problem with DNS (17.10)

Tags: network-manager, dns

Fresh installation of Ubuntu 17.10. After 1 day of use, I couldn't get access to webpages. It was a DNS problem. Every time I restart Ubuntu I get this in `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# Generated by Connection Managernameserver ::1
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

After writing manually the `resolv.conf` file indicating a DNS server (google) each time after I reboot, I can get access to Internet.

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

However, when I connect to a corporate VPN, I experience the same problem again, I cannot access web pages. If I disconnect the VPN, the DNS appears to work again.

System information: http://paste.ubuntu.com/26024991/

Answer (score 1):

Probably DNS configuration gets pushed from VPN client. Why it is pointing to lo address - check servers configs if possible.

I believe you have a line like this on the servers openvpn file:
`push "dhcp-option DNS 127.0.0.1"`

To override this, do simply:

```
echo -e "nameserver 8.8.8.8\n nameserver 8.8.4.4" > /etc/resolv.conf

chmod 444 /etc/resolv.conf

chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

chattr will set immutable bit, so the file doesn't get overwritten.

*PS (maybe resolv.conf is managed by systemd somewhere else - idk i do not use sysd )*

Answer (score -1):

Please edit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf:

```
 dns=default
```

then, restart NM service...

Comment: Please take your time to create a good answer by explaining what this does, why it is useful and how it solves the problem at hand.